# Is there some log files for Azure Cloud Services for the WaIISHost crashes

Tags: azure

In the cloud service  run method we are running some unmanaged code. Everything have worked up until now but it started randomly to crash th WaIISHost and restarting the WebRole.

I am wondering if there is some log files on the system ( remote desktoping in) where I might be able to find some information about what causes the crash?

I have tried to catch/try everything but it just crashes without hitting any of them. (Some of the unmanaged code is running in other app domains and it makes things alittle more complicated to debug, so any log files from the WaIIHost and why it crashes would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx which outlines all of the diagnostics information on a PaaS VM.  In particular you will be interested in the event logs, WaIISHost logs, and WER logs.

Also in that blog post is a series of troubleshooting posts that will help you walk through how to troubleshoot in a PaaS environment.  You will also find AzureTools which may help you in debugging WaIISHost.exe using something like DebugDiag or WinDBG.

Log locations from the blog post:

**Application Event Logs** – Event Viewer –> Windows Logs –> Application
◦This is standard troubleshooting for both Azure and on-premise servers.  You will often find w3wp.exe related errors in these logs.

**WaIISHost Logs** - C:\Resources\Directory{DeploymentID}.{Rolename}.DiagnosticStore\WaIISHost.log
◦This contains logs from the WaIISHost.exe process which is where your role entrypoint code (ie. WebRole.cs) runs for WebRoles.  The majority of this information is also included in other logs covered above (ie. the Windows Azure Event Logs), but you may occasionally find additional useful information here.

**WER** - Located in C:\Dumps